# pandas fill null values by the mean of that category (use loop?)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to fill in the missing data in the data set based on the average of the values observed during that year, and it takes a long time to write one by one. I can't create this structure with a for loop. How should it be coded?

```py
df['TOTAL_REVENUE'] = df.TOTAL_REVENUE.fillna(df.groupby('YEAR')['TOTAL_REVENUE'].transform('mean'))  
df['FEDERAL_REVENUE'] = df.FEDERAL_REVENUE.fillna(df.groupby('YEAR')['FEDERAL_REVENUE'].transform('mean'))  
df['STATE_REVENUE'] = df.STATE_REVENUE.fillna(df.groupby('YEAR')['STATE_REVENUE'].transform('mean'))   
df['TOTAL_EXPENDITURE'] = df.TOTAL_EXPENDITURE.fillna(df.groupby('YEAR')['TOTAL_EXPENDITURE'].transform('mean'))
```

I know it's wrong but I wanted to show it as an example .

```py
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df.column.fillna(df.groupby('YEAR')[column].transform('mean'))  
    #df['TOTAL_REVENUE'] = df.TOTAL_REVENUE.fillna(df.groupby('YEAR')['TOTAL_REVENUE'].transform('mean'))
```

[A screenshot as an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMc9v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd do it like this (use `df[column]` instead of `df.column`):

```
for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].fillna(df.groupby('YEAR')[column].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: Hey richardec,  this code gives error like this DataError: No numeric types to aggregate. but when i flip all the columns one by one there is actually no problem

Comment: Was your old repetitive code working?

Comment: Yes its working

Comment: You might need to make a list of the columns you want to process and loop over that instead of `df.columns`. Probably the problem is that there are some columns in `df` that this code shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Or, you can specific a list of columns that you **don't** want the code to loop over. In that case, you'd loop over `df.drop(['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], axis=1).columns` instead of `df.columns`

Comment: I missed it, you are right, thank you very much, the solution was fast :)